# glide does'nt load the picture from storage firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

Glide doesn't load the picture from storage firebase.

Here are the dependencies that I added.

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
```

And here's the function that I use.

```
private void getUserInfo(){
    mCustomerDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){
                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                if(map.get("name")!=null){
                    mName = map.get("name").toString();
                    mNameField.setText(mName);
                }
                if(map.get("phone")!=null){
                    mPhone = map.get("phone").toString();
                    mPhoneField.setText(mPhone);
                }
                if(map.get("profileImageUrl")!=null){
                    mProfileImageUrl = map.get("profileImageUrl").toString();
                    Glide.with(getApplication()).load(mProfileImageUrl).into(mProfileImage);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

NB: it was work perfectly before I upgrade the Gradle list to androidx

Before registration

[image]

After registration

[image]

Comment: This article might be helpful for you  https://medium.com/@egemenhamutcu/displaying-images-from-firebase-storage-using-glide-for-kotlin-projects-3e4950f6c103

Comment: What is the error that you see in the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you could actually download the profile image before updating it to `androidx`. Looks like the image that you have is the default image for that `ImageView`.

I would actually suggest the following.

1. Check if you have the INTERNET permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   ```
2. Use the following to add a placeholder image while you are trying to load the images using Glide.

   ```
   Glide.with(getApplication())
        .load(mProfileImageUrl)
        .apply(new RequestOptions()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.default_person)
            .fitCenter())
        .into(mProfileImage);
   ```

Comment: I have it in the following Glide version - `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'`